# Unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING error in SQL Query

Tags: mysql, wordpress, encapsulation

I am getting an unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING error in the following SQL query:

```
mysql_query (UPDATE 'wp_posts' SET 'post_status' = 'publish' WHERE 'post_id' = '$id');
```

Can you guys see where the error might be?

Here is the full code in case it helps:

```
    $key = 'feed';
    $post_ids = array(2263, 2249); 

    foreach ($post_ids as $id) {
    $feedurl = get_post_custom_values($key, $id);
    $feedurlstr = implode($feedurl);

    // Ignore - it determines whether feed is live and returns $result
    LiveOrNot($feedurlstr);

    if ( $result == "live" ) {
    mysql_query (UPDATE 'wp_posts' SET 'post_status' = 'publish' WHERE 'post_id' = '$id');
    }    
    elseif ( $result == "notlive" ) {
    mysql_query (UPDATE 'wp_posts' SET 'post_status' = 'draft' WHERE 'post_id' = '$id');
    }
    endif;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap your SQL statements in quote-marks - `"`.

```
mysql_query ("UPDATE 'wp_posts' SET 'post_status' = 'publish' WHERE 'post_id' = '$id'");
```

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_query()` takes a string. PHP is looking for constants interspersed with strings, which is not valid PHP grammer.

You need to delimit your strings, `'` and `"` are popular choices, but there is also Heredoc syntax.

[Read more about strings in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).